# CakePHP 3.2 validation messages in foreign languages

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.x

What is the suggested way in CakePHP 3.2 to change the validation messages to the messagess, which are displayed in the languages different than English? For example, how to customize the notEmpty message in all places of its occurence at the same time?

```
[_empty] => This field cannot be left empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggest way is to translate these message in appropriate `.po`/`.mo` language files. Extract the messages via the I18n shell, and you'll find something like

```generic
#: Validation/Validator.php:104
msgid "This field cannot be left empty"
msgstr ""
```

in the generated `.pot` template file(s), ready for translation.

Alternatively custom messages can be passed to the corresponding validation rule, like

```php
$validator->notEmpty('field_name', 'custom error message');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > I18N Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html)**